# DialogFlow V2 Text query quota

Tags: dialogflow-es

I've faced an issue with text query limitations in DialogFlow v2 agents. In my app I'm accessing a couple of agents at the same time. The problem is that, when I`m sending query to agents I can only send around 90 request per minute when accessing two agents. Is this suppose to be this way?

Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0):

There are different quotas for different editions of Dialogflow. Depending on your plan Standard or Enterprise and use it may be different. You can check out the quotas for your plan and agent [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/quotas).

Comment: I know about quotas and I'm using standart quota (180 text requests to agent per minute). The problem is, when I'm accessing two dialogflow agents at the same time (using the same google app to generate credentials), dialogflow doesn't allow me to send 180 requests.

Comment: It looks it is dividing the quota between the two agents, 90 each as you have mentioned. Try to transfer one agent to other user account and see if that way you are receiving 180.

Comment: It looks it is dividing the quota between the two agents, 90 each as you have mentioned. Try to transfer one agent to other user account and see if that way you are receiving 180.

Comment: is this limitation applies for per session or for all the sessions, because 10 requests per second seems to be very less for a bot in production. any idea?